# Pandas - Pipe Delimiter exists in Field Value causing Bad Lines

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to import a text file like so:

```
data = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt', sep='|', quoting=3, 
                    error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin1', low_memory=False)
```

I'm getting an error on 1 line because the field value has a Pipe found within it. When it attempts to parse the row, it finds that the length of the row is too long throwing an error. It allows the file to process; however, this row is missing.

Example:

Row -

```
4321|Test|1/2/1900
1234|Test||1/1/1900
```

Parsing this file will create:

```
4321   Test    1/2/1900
1234   Test               1/1/1900
```

I want to eliminate the extra | in the second row "Test|" or allow pandas to understand that it exists to create:

```
4321   Test    1/2/1900
1234   Test    1/1/1900
```

or this would be fine:

```
 1234   Test|    1/1/1900
```

I have attempted to use converters, other quoting methods (quotchars, etc), but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to get by this? All recommendations welcome.

Eric

Comment: Can you guarantee this is a problem with *only* the first line?

Comment: Well, it's not actually the first line. It's line 116950 of the file. It will be random; however, I could potentially strip that string column out because I don't need it. Not sure how to evaluate the file before pandas consumes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to remove any instance of "||" then use pandas. An example of this would be:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


buffer= StringIO()
with open(r'filepath.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "||" not in line:
            buffer.write(line)




buffer.seek(0)
data = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep='|', quoting=3,
                    error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin1', low_memory=False)
```

You could also do it outside of python with a find and replace operation.

Comment: I considered this as an option. Unfortunately, NULL values and Non-NULL values exist within the file inside the same column, so this option would generate the same issue, just on different rows.

Comment: Are you okay with dropping every row that contains a null value?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm good with just deleting the whole column, if possible. I'd just like to do it programmatically instead of manually. I'm willing to accept any possible solution.

Comment: This causes my file to drop to only 2 rows as most rows have a NULL value found in an individual column. It ignores all the rows where '||' is found. I think I may just have to request the file delimiter to be changed.

Comment: Sorry, I asked if you were okay with dropping rows with null values. Misunderstanding